# How to replace a letter with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, replace, python-requests

I have this code in Python. It is running good. The problem is with two last href's, they have "ä" in it so it is not a link anymore. How can I replace "ä" with "%c3%a4" so it will open the right website?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/"
req = requests.get(url)
src = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

all_categories = soup.find_all("a", class_="gc-link gc-link--blue")
for i in all_categories:
    print("https://www.gelbeseiten.de" + i.get("href"))
```

Comment: it is still valid URL, you can use lib urllib -> urllib.parse.unquote(i.get("href")) or reverse quote("ä") -> "%c3%a4". Try unquote_plus and quote_plus if you need

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing it with `.replace` method.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/"
req = requests.get(url)
src = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

all_categories = soup.find_all("a", class_="gc-link gc-link--blue")
for i in all_categories:
    print("https://www.gelbeseiten.de" + i.get("href").replace('ä','%c3%a4'))
```